# WebPartTitleID differences between ASP.NET webparts and Sharepoint webparts

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

when I reference **Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart** 
the WebPartTitleID is generated on pages  in the following format. WebPartTitleWPQ2

when I reference the **System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart**

the WebPartTitleID is generated on pages  like the following

WebPartTitlectl00_m_g_cfe73da2_e9aa_44e3_aa10_b8a300837217

is there a way to control this so I get the WPQ pattern on the asp.net webpart ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to control these auto-generated web part ID's. If you need to style them, the best thing I've been able to do is wrap everything is a div with a custom ID or class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
string clientName = ((Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart)wp).ClientName;

string wpqId = clientName.Substring(clientName.IndexOf("WPQ"));
```